# Multicluster istio without exposing kubeconfig between clusters

Tags: istio

I managed to get multicluster istio working following the [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/primary-remote_multi-network/).

However this requires the kubeconfig of the clusters to be setup on each other. I am looking for an alternative to doing that. Based on presentation from solo.io and [admiral](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2020/multi-cluster-mesh-automation/), it seems that it might be possible to setup ServiceEntries to accomplish this manually. Istio docs are scarce in this this area. Does anyone have pointers on how to make this work?

There are some advantages to setting up the discovery manually or thru our CD processes...

- if one cluster gets compromised, the creds to other clusters dont leak
- allows us to limit the which services are discovered

I posted the question on [twitter](https://twitter.com/k__raman/status/1419158013525463040) as well and hope to get some feedback from the Istio contributors.

Answer (score 0):

As per Admiral [docs](https://github.com/istio-ecosystem/admiral/blob/master/docs/Architecture.md):

> Admiral acts as a controller watching k8s clusters that have a credential stored as a secret object which the namespace Admiral is running in. Admiral delivers Istio configuration to each cluster to enable services to communicate.

No matter how you manage contol-plane configuration (manually or with controller) - you have store and provision credentials somehow. In this case with use of the secrets

---

You can store your secrets securely in git with [sealed-secrets](https://github.com/bitnami-labs/sealed-secrets).
You can read more [here](https://learnk8s.io/kubernetes-secrets-in-git).

Comment: amended the question to explain why I want to setup the discovery manually or via CD

Comment: Edited my answer and added info about keeping your secrets secure.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. The issue is not that the secrets are not secure in git.
If an attacker gets access to my kube cluster, they may be able to see the kube config that is stored for istio mesh to do discovery and then gain access to the other clusters that have been registered.

Comment: There is no other way than to store those secrets inside the cluster.